# Specflow - There is a way to Set-Cookie on web automated tests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, cookies, automated-tests, specflow

I'm automating a test in a ASP.NET MVC 5 application, which needs to start with cookies set.

I tried to simulate a response attribute change, but the response of the BrowserWindowContext couldn't be altered.

Has anyone else worked on this issue?

```
[BeforeScenario("workitem[38419]")]
public void BeforeScenario()
{
    if (ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Contains("workitem[38419][cookies]"))
    {
        var teste  = ScenarioContext.Current;
        var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(new Uri(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("Url")));
        request.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        response.Cookies = request.CookieContainer.GetCookies(request.RequestUri);
        var keyValue = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings.Get("cookie");
        var cookie = new Cookie() {
            Domain = request.RequestUri.Host.ToString(),
            Name = keyValue.Split(';')[0],
            Value = keyValue.Split(';')[1]
            };
        response.Cookies.Add(cookie);                
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you calling the application in your test?

Comment: Are you doing functional tests through the browser or are you unit testing your controllers?

Comment: if you don't even respond to questions then no-one is likely to help you with your problems

Comment: I'm doing a functional tests, in the SpecflowBase class the BrowserWindowContext.Current is setted , but i din't find a way to change de response.

Comment: Sorry about the late response, i'm from brasil and the time is diferent.